# Find gap in list with datetimes (start/end)

Tags: python

In my Python code I have generated two lists, one for start times and one for end times. They cover one day.

I have converted it to datetime.datetime.

They map start[n] -> end[n]

I need to find empty times during the day(00:00 -> 23:59), not covered by the times in the start/end lists.
What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Start:

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 23, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 7, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 19, 0)]
```

End:

```
[datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 23, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 7, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 19, 0)]
```

Comment: start and end you posted are the same..

Comment: what did you try and where did it lack? [mre]?

Comment: hint: create a list of time "ranges" (can be tuples of `(start, end)`), sort them, and go in ascending order keeping the ranges between each `end` and next `start` as the uncovered times

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is to group the start time and end time together, then sort the ranges by start time so that we can iterate through them and find consecutive ones. In order to satisfy the requirement of keeping things in one day, we can add "virtual" tasks at the end of each day so that we force the algorithm to split them properly.

```py
def find_free_time(
    start, end
) -> list[tuple[datetime.datetime, datetime.timedelta]]:
    """
    This function takes in a list of datetimes and returns a list of free time between
    
    Args:
     - tasks_start: list of datetime objects representing the start
     - tasks_end: list of datetime objects representing the end
    
    Returns:
    list of tuples : 
        - first element is the start of the free time
        - second element is the duration of the free time
    """
    # Find all the unique days
    days = set([task.date() for task in start])
    # Add a 0 second task to the end of the day to represent the end of the day
    for day in days:
        start.append(datetime.datetime(day.year, day.month, day.day, 23, 59, 59))
        end.append(datetime.datetime(day.year, day.month, day.day, 23, 59, 59))

    # This will force the algorithm to split the ranges by day

    # Group the times into a list of start, end tuples
    ranges = list(zip(start, end))
    # Sort the ranges by start time so that we know exactly when the free time is
    ranges.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    # Find the free time between ranges
    free_time = []

    # We iterate through the tasks and find the free time between them
    for i in range(1, len(ranges)):
        if ranges[i - 1][1] < ranges[i][0]:  # Check if there is time between the ranges
            free_start = ranges[i - 1][1]
            free_end = ranges[i][0]
            free_delta = free_end - free_start
            free_time.append((free_start, free_delta))

    return free_time
```

I hope you will find this useful.

Tip for the future : it is often useful in python to group together things that go together, for example here the start and end time. This might not be always optimal in memory efficient programming languages but for python the few nanoseconds you might lose in memory access you gain in time writing your code and in clarity.